# How to load Javascript and its dependencies?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have script A which loads another script B:

```
$.getScript('B.js',foo);
```

But what if `B` also loads a script? Then I would like that `foo` was executed after `B` is loaded **AND** the script it loads. So `foo` is executed after entire chain is loaded.

Please note that `B` dependencies should be transparent to `A`, so I cannot just add scripts to `A` instead of `B`.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to your problem is to use the AMD pattern and RequireJS

Here are some links for reading about AMD:

http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html

http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/

Specifically,

> The AMD module format itself is a proposal for defining modules where
>   both the module and dependencies can be asynchronously loaded. It has
>   a number of distinct advantages including being both asynchronous and
>   highly flexible by nature which removes the tight coupling one might
>   commonly find between code and module identity.

For example, your code could be updated like this:

```
define(['foo', 'B'], function(fooModule,B){
   // at this point, if you have a foo.js file that provides function foo(){},
   // plus B.js is loaded
   fooModule.foo();

});
```

But this requires you to have (at least) three other files:

foo.js

```
define(function(){
   return {
     foo : function () {
        // this foo function doesn't depend on any other modules
     };
  });
```

B.js

```
define(['A'],function(A){
   function privateBfunction1() {
      // can use A's interface here
      A.publicA();
   }

   function publicBfunction2() {
      // can use A's interface here
   }

   // public api
   return {
     publicB : publicBfunction2
  };
});
```

A.js

```
// another way to specify no dependencies, an empty array and no function args
define([],function(){

   // public api
   return {
     publicA :    function publicAfunction2() {
     }

  };
});
```

Comment: I didn't expected that for bicycle-level problem there is space-shuttle solution :-) I ended up with lame 2-line hack, but it is useful to know there is tool for complex scenarios, thank you!

Comment: Very well said...yes, it is a space shuttle solution to a bicycle-level problem.  IMO, use AMD for larger projects (large number of files) that include a compile/build step that packages up all your JS/CSS/HTML template files.  AMD is definitely not a solution for every packaging problem.

Comment: @gre  I read this today, another approach (among many i.e. grunt, gulp, commonJS, requirejs) to resolving module dependency, this time as a build step (which doesn't directly answer your `$.getScript` code, but I think it's worth a read http://substack.net/task_automation_with_npm_run

Answer (score 3):

For complex inter-script dependencies I think the only way out is to use a module engine, in this case RequireJS.

Assuming you are the programmer behind A and B, for each module, you can use RequireJS functions to declare their existence as module, and indicate on which other module each depends (this is done through the define() function from RequireJS).

Then you can load them all with the require() function from RequireJS and the engine will load the scripts in the appropriate order.